# TYPO3 auto deleting item from object storage

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18. I have some model video. video has object storage field comments mm relation table. And in BE I can delete comment from general list. I want set auto deleting comment from object storage and from mm table when I delete comment. I hope you understand my problem. Help  me please, I really need it very much and I have not any ideas (

Comment: Do you want auto deletion in the Backend or in your extbase plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `@cascade remove` to your video model, like it is mentioned here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/singlehtml/#implementing-relationships-between-domain-objects